# Car rent with International driving licence in UK after lived in UK more than 1 year

Tags: car-rentals, tips-and-tricks, automobiles

I recently met a problem about renting a car in UK. I came from China and have lived in UK for around 2 years. The UK licence I just got is less than one year so most car hire company won't rent a car to me (even Enterprise did not give to me because of the new system ). However, technically, I can rent a car with my Chinese licence since it is older than 2 years.

So can I rent a car with the Chinese licence since I can drive in UK technically because I have a valid UK licence?

Answer (score 6):

According to two British government guides (linked below), you can only drive on your foreign drivers license in the UK for a maximum of a year after you enter the country, so the answer is no - while the foreign license is still valid in the country of issue, its grace period in the UK has past.

- https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence
- https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence

If you do succeed in renting the vehicle under your Chinese license and are stopped by the police, you could technically be charged with driving without a valid license and thus driving without valid insurance (and your UK license would potentially only cover you for that first charge - the insurance would still be invalid).

Comment: The issue, as I understand it, is that the car rental companies refuse to give Robert a car because he's had his British license for less than one year, which makes him look like a new driver. So the question is, can he use his Chinese license to prove that he's an experienced driver, and his new British license to prove that he can legally use the roads?

Comment: @DavidRicherby thats entirely up to the carhire company and is not answerable here, but I would suggest "no" because the UK driving license time limit they are running into here is down to insurance, and that won't change - they do not have a valid Chinese license to drive in the UK because the grace period has expired, and thus they are insured under their UK license details, which only show a given amount of experience.  I doubt that, given he fills the role of a resident in this country, a car hire company would accept the Chinese license knowing it has no validity in the UK at this time.

Comment: As @DavidRicherby alludes, I don't think the driver could be cited for driving without a valid license because he would be driving with his valid UK license.  The fact that he used a different license to rent the car doesn't mean that he can't show the UK license to the police.  THe insurance question is more likely to be a problem, though.

Comment: @phoog if he showed his UK driving license if stopped, he would (as I suggest earlier) have insurance issues, but he would also potentially have issues with the hire itself, if the car hire company is notified of the issue - they could take action for a fraudulent hire, as his Chinese license has no validity in the UK after the grace period and should not have been used to hire the vehicle.

Comment: @phoog In clarification of my comment above, a car hire agreement has "authorised persons" in it, which are those people allowed to drive the car.  In this case, the OP has *two* personas - his Chinese one under his Chinese license, and his UK one under his UK license.  Unless both of these are listed on the agreement and they hired the car using the Chinese license but they presented the UK license if stopped, technically the OP would have breached the conditions of the hire, and they could *technically* be cited for taking the vehicle without the owners consent, as the consent is conditional

Comment: The "two personas" analysis strikes me as unlikely to get much traction in a court.  The argument that they (perhaps fraudulently) rented the car by presenting an invalid Chinese license (invalid on account of more than 1 year residence in the UK) doesn't require the "two personas" analysis, of course.

Comment: @Moo Does this distinction between "person" and "persona" have any basis in English law? You seem to be arguing that Robert-who-presents-you-with-a-Chinese-license is legally a different person from Robert-who-presents-you-with-a-British-license, and I find that hard to believe. (The claim that the insurance is contingent on having a UK license that's been valid for more than a year seems much more plausible.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not arguing that its a different person, I'm arguing that the service is granted under specific consent, and that consent is given on the basis of one set of credentials, not the other.  To the car hire company, Robert-who-presents-you-with-a-Chinese-license is a separate person to Robert-who-presents-you-with-a-UK-license, because one of those licenses is technically valid to hire the car under their terms (when the grace period validity is ignored), but not the other.

Comment: @DavidRicherby in the reply to phoog, the point is that if stopped, presenting the UK license may indeed land you in hot water, because although it is a valid UK license, its not got any link to the consent to drive the car.  So you would be lacking two things - consent and insurance.  And both of those are dependent on which set of credentials you presented when hiring the car - hence two personas, same person, but treated as different people depending.

Comment: @Moo No, they're the same person. Your conclusion may well be correct but any argument based on Robert-Chinese-license being a different person from Robert-UK-license is nonsense. And there's nothing to stop him presenting _both_ licenses simultaneously!

Comment: @DavidRicherby its not nonsense because one has consent and the other does not.  Same person, but treated entirely differently depending on how they present themselves with regard to license.  Hence my point.

Comment: @Moo There is only one person. That person either has consent or not. Again, your _conclusion_ may well be true (it sounds plausible, I honestly don't know but I'm happy to give you the benefit of the doubt) but your reasoning makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby let me put it another way - consent is conditional, and in this case its conditional on having a license that has been held for longer than a given period (eliminating the UK license for the purpose of hiring and driving the hire car) and is valid in the UK for the duration of the hire (eliminating the Chinese license).  If the Chinese license is fraudulently presented as valid when hiring the vehicle, the consent for hiring and driving the vehicle is linked to that license.  Not the person.  The license.  Because its the license which gets the person the insurance.

Comment: @DavidRicherby up until a couple of months ago I was senior web dev for a UK insurance broker, and this system is one of the ones I was responsible for for a couple of large underwriters and large car hire companies.  The consent is not linked to the person, its linked to the validity to drive.  Once that validity evaporates (eg the license presented at time of hiring is invalid), the consent also evaporates, regardless of the fact that you are legally allowed to drive under other credentials.

Comment: @Moo: You should clarify that you are using the pre-brexit meaning of "foreign", I.e.: not an EEA national.